# Android Studio - Button onClick() is not working

Tags: android

I have two buttons on my main Activity, which both should lead to another activity, but when I run the code it is showing an error.

MainActivity.java is this:

```
package com.assignment2.courier;

import static android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.V;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    public void second (View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, adelivery.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
    }
}
```

This is the button code in activity_main.xml

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="234dp"
        android:onClick="second"
        android:text="Arrange Delivery"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Error:
[Failed to compile values file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XjJc.png)

What is the problem here?

Comment: Please move second method outside onCreate method , function can't be defined inside another function in java . Also , please post complete compile error message and values file contents as the attached screenshot doesn't contain any details about the compilation error .

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the `second` function is inside the `onCreate`

You need to adapt the code as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void second (View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, adelivery.class);
    startActivity(i);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move second method out of the onCreate method; this is the problem in your code.